# 'Sort by' option effect all other customer

Tags: customer, cache, sorting

I setup default 'Sort by' option as 'Positions' but I found when other customer changed 'Sort by' option like 'Name' on front-end, it effect to me too (I can see 'Sort by' is now 'Name' even if I didn't change option and I guess it also effect all other customer's view)

How can I make 'Sort by' option is not effect to other customers even if a customer change and show default 'Sort by' option first as always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you are right when saying one customer behaviour affects others. Read this [article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/) and you will be able to set the default sort order.
Also, it is fairly possible that you changed yourself/miss configured the sort order and now you are seeing the sort by Name.

Comment: Thank you for reply and link Maybe i'm not right but It's clear the Sort by option is different sometime when I visit my store I checked the article . and I check my setting 'Product Listing Sort by' - ' Best Value' is my option now but I can see there is no 'Best Value' on my front-end and category admin page, I can see 'Position' 'Name' 'Price' option on frontand the Position option is what I want as default option but there is no 'Position' sort by option on admin page (On admin only 'Best Value' 'Naem' 'Price' option)

Comment: I tried this in a fresh Magento installation and it seems to work fine. The way to configure default sort orders are correct too, you might want to try this in a Private browsing window to check it without cookies and sessions.